# translate wordpress website from english to arabic

Tags: plugins, translation

I install weglot plugin and add arabic as destiantion language but when change website from english to arabic i get this error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /ar/ was not found on this server
```

how can i solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might help https://support.weglot.com/article/76-wordpress-404-error-translating, it's exactly the same error you have.
It seems to be about permalinks.